# Counting points a on linestring

Tags: sql, postgis

I am trying to counts the number of points on a line for each row in the following table

```
CREATE TABLE outils.prod(
pk  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
cable VARCHAR (25),
PA  VARCHAR (10),       
Art VARCHAR(7),
FT      Numeric,
BT      Numeric
);

INSERT INTO  outils.prod  (pk)
SELECT id_ftth 
FROM outils.cable
WHERE type_cable = '2' ;

SELECT ADDGEOMETRYCOLUMN('outils','prod','geom',2154,'MultiLineString',2);
```

I have tried to update my line table but i have trouble getting an answer for each row.

```
UPDATE outils.prod SET FT=(SELECT COUNT( ST_INTERSECTION(outils.prod.geom,outils.ft.geom))
 FROM outils.prod , outils.ft)
```

With the above  code i managed to get the total number of intersection for every line but i would like to have the count by line in my line table.

Thank you ,
Hugo

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a sub-query to do the count per line.

Also you don't need to compute the intersection (the geom), but just to check if they intersect, which is much faster.

```
UPDATE outils.prod 
SET FT= sub.cnt
FROM (
 SELECT pk, count(*) as cnt
 FROM outils.ft
 JOIN outils.prod ON ST_INTERSECTS(prod.geom, ft.geom)
)
WHERE prod.pk = sub.pk;
```

Comment: Hi thanks  a lot for the feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: @duckrichard great! Please consider marking the answer as accepted (green check mark to the left) so others know there is a working solution